# How to deal with over-represented features in anomaly detection

Tags: anomaly-detection, feature-engineering

Let me illustrate the problem with an example:

Our dataset consists of a collection of letters written to Santa Claus **mostly by kids** together with the age of the person who wrote them. We want to run anomaly detection on this. We have 1 integer feature for the age and 1000 features for the letter's body (because we have chosen a bag of words approach, e.g. tf-idf).

Lets say that I fit an neural auto-encoder or an isolation forest to this dataset. Is it a problem to have defined the feature space like this?

My intuition is that yes. Ideally, I would like my anomaly detection model to pick up on the weird case where a "normal" letter is written by a **84 y/o person**. My fear is that there will be a tendency of that not happening, because the age (1 feature) is under-represented in comparison to the text (1000 features).

If I am right, to what extent will dimensionality reduction techniques like PCA/SVD on the text features help? I mean, maybe I can reduce the space from 1000 to 30 before starting to lose most of the information in the text features, but even then 1 vs 30 still would still look disproportionate to me.

Answer (score 0):

What aspect of the text is interesting for the anomaly scoring, you think? It it is the content in general, ie what they write about, you can try to apply some topic modeling to reduce the dimensionality.
Latent Dirichlet Allocation is a good start for that. 
https://medium.com/nanonets/topic-modeling-with-lsa-psla-lda-and-lda2vec-555ff65b0b05

Then apply Isolation Forest to that. In general I would not be so worried about not catching old people writing as anomalies. I think instead what might happen is that all old people are flagged as anomalies, because they are rare.

Comment: I simplified my statement, but I am actually applying truncated singular value decomposition to my bag of words - which approximates LSA - and reduces dimensions from 1000 to 100, but no more. So you still have an imbalanced representation of features. Regarding your second paragraph, old people are not flagged as anomalies either way, because its only the age which is weird (1 feature) versus the written text which is normal (100 or 1000 features).